# Cancel timout / timer if function called again --- debounce function

Tags: javascript, timer, debouncing

I want to create a function that starts a timeout, but if the function is called again, before the timer ends, cancel the original call and start the timer again.

I thought I could do:

```
function setTimer() {
   setTimeout(() => {
      // do something
   }, 3000)
}
```

...but that doesn't work, for every time I run setTimer(), it doesn't cancel the original call.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Based on what you've described, what you're looking for is called "debounce".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns an id you can use to clear that timeout with `clearTimeout()`. So you can clear the existing timeout at the beginning of your function.

For example if you keep clicking it will keep restarting -- if you don't click it finishes in 2 seconds:

```js
let timerID;

function setTimer() {
  console.log("starting/restarting timer")
  clearTimeout(timerID)
  timerID = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("finished")
  }, 2000)
}
```

```html
<p onclick="setTimer()">click to start</p>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is cancel the existing timeout and start it over? You can do this by using [`cleartimeout`](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/dom/Window/clearTimeout/)

```
let timeoutFunctionVar = null;

const setTimeoutFunction = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutFunctionVar)
    timeoutFunctionVar = setTimeout(() => {
        // do something
    }, 3000)
};

setTimeoutFunction()
```

So every time `setTimeoutFunction()` gets called, the previous timeout gets reset

Answer (score 2):

I figured this question gets asked frequently, especially for searches triggered by key events, but I couldn't find any.

The basic idea is that you keep the [timeout id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) stateful, so you can clear  it on subsequent invocations to the TO setter:

```
const MS_IN_SEC = 1000;

let old_timeout;

function TO_setter(searchString) {
    if (old_timeout)
        window.clearTimeout(old_timeout);

    old_timeout = window.setTimeout(search, 2 * MS_IN_SEC, searchString);
}

function search(s) {
    console.log('search for: %s', s);
}
```

Comment: I assumed that also, but I couldn't find anything either.