# JavaScript | Restart a timer if function is called again

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a javascript function to reveal a hidden div for a few seconds, then re-hide the div.  However, I want to be able to click to re-hide the div as well.  In that case, if the div is clicked 3 times, the div will automatically be hidden when the timer runs out based on when the function was executed after the first click.  I added this "clearTimeout" thinking it would reset the timer, but it doesn't seem to be working.  What am I missing to reset a timeout on each execution of this function?

```
function show(div) {

    let timeFunction;
    clearTimeout(timeFunction);
    timeFunction = setTimeout(function () { myFunction() }, 3000);

    div.classList.add("hidden");

}
```

Comment: Simply said, you're trying to implement debounce on hiding the div. Check this out: https://medium.com/@griffinmichl/implementing-debounce-in-javascript-eab51a12311e and also I think you need to change `classList.add` to `classList.toggle`

Comment: Scope..... you create a new variable ever click `let timeFunction;
function show(div) {`

Comment: Just define the `timeFunction` outside the function. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377081/cancel-timout-timer-if-function-called-again-debounce-function#

Comment: Thank you all so much!  Apologies for the repeat question... Couldn't find this question beforehand